# How to make Select Directory using React?

Tags: html, reactjs, folderbrowserdialog

I need to upload all files from a folder to server.
I'm trying to implement Select Directory window, and not Select file.

The normal way like:

```
<input type="file" webkitdirectory directory/>
```

Did not work for me, and showed Select File window.

But when I created empty regular html file with this input tag, it was working fine.
Does anybody know how to implement the solution using React?

Thank you!

Comment: Rich Warrior answer is correct just select directory and push Upload buton. https://codesandbox.io/embed/dreamy-bouman-kswbg

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try [bheptinh](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3468#issuecomment-448336672).

```
<input directory="" webkitdirectory="" type="file" />
```

Comment: I am glad to help

Comment: sorry I tried to extract the path from this element and I got my path something like `C:\Downloads\fakepath\firstFileInsideChosenPath.txt` I need the actual selected path. Can someone help me on this please?

Answer (score 2):

**In React 17 with Typescript, if you are using useRef Hook**, the best bet is to extend React's HTMLAttributes (in the same file of your input) and then simply add directory and webkitdirectory attributes in input tag as

```
import * as React from "react";

export const ImportForm: React.FunctionComponent<FormProps> = (props) => {
const folderInput= React.useRef(null);

return (
<>
           <div className="form-group row">
              <div className="col-lg-6">
                <label>Select Folder</label>
              </div>
              <div className="col-lg-6">
                <input
                  type="file"  
                  directory=""
                  webkitdirectory=""                
                  className="form-control"
                  ref={folderInput}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
</>)
};

declare module 'react' {
  interface HTMLAttributes<T> extends AriaAttributes, DOMAttributes<T> {
    // extends React's HTMLAttributes
    directory?: string;        // remember to make these attributes optional....
    webkitdirectory?: string;
  }
}
```