# PowerApps - How do I create a folder picker

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-component-framework

I'm building a **canvas** PowerApp / Component using React and FluentUI (office-fabric-ui).
(if that limits the ways to solve this feel free to ignore the React part)

Using `context.device.pickFile()` ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/component-framework/reference/device/pickfile)) I can trigger a file picker dialog. I added this to my component, tested that in a PowerApp and it works as you'd expect.

However, what I am really looking for is a folder browser. Of course I could ask the user to use the filePicker to select a file in a directory and then get the directory name from that, but that's just a workaround... and what if there is no file to pick in the target directory?

Is there a way to trigger a folder browser?

Answer (score 0):

From [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57324261/7920473), I believe the below snippet should work.

```
<input directory="" webkitdirectory="" type="file" />
```

You can play round and experience it using this [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/dreamy-bouman-kswbg).

Comment: I'll give this a go, but the "This will upload all files from `DIRECTORY NAME`. Only do this if you trust the site" bit makes me afraid it'll actually attempt to upload all files.

I just want it to give me the folder name, but it's worth a shot!

Comment: @TerrySeidler: I think you’re looking for tree view control kinda browser but not file upload control.

Comment: Yeah, that's it! :}

Comment: @TerrySeidler, try this: https://codeburst.io/practical-recursion-implementing-a-file-tree-view-in-react-electron-af62e7b46d26

Comment: We have abandoned the idea - really need a native folder browser, but it does not seem to be possible at this time. Thanks for trying though :)

Comment: @TerrySeidler yeah, we don’t have OOB control for that, but PCF is the way to go to develop a new component/control using react, typescript