# ReactJS - Adding attributes to a reference object created with useRef Hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In my class component I have a ref object to select files from a selected folder. So, I add attributes `directory` and `webkitdirectory` in componentDidMount as

```
export class ImportForm extends React.Component<ImportFormProps,ImportFormState> {
  constructor(props:ImportFormProps){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      folderInput: React.createRef()
    }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    if (this.state.folderInput.current !== null) {
      this.state.folderInput.current.setAttribute("directory", "");
      this.state.folderInput.current.setAttribute("webkitdirectory", "");
    }
  }
.
.
.
```

I'm changing the above class component to FunctionComponent. Now, I'm using useRef react hook to use folder reference. But adding attributes `directory` and `webkitdirectory` is not adding these attributes to my folder selection input. That is, my input element is not working as it was working in class component.
Here is my code

```
export const ImportForm : React.FunctionComponent<ImportFormProps> = (
  props
) => {
  const folderInput = React.useRef(null);
  

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (folderInput.current !== null) {
      folderInput.current.setAttribute("directory", "");
      folderInput.current.setAttribute("webkitdirectory", "");
    }
  }, [folderInput]);
```

**Is useEffect hook right place to add these attributes?**

What I'm doing wrong?

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57330579/7344164) but not working.

Thanks!

Comment: What worked for me is https://stackoverflow.com/a/64869793/7344164

Comment: Hi. Did you solve this issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57324261/how-to-make-select-directory-using-react/64869793#64869793

Answer (score -2):

I did not see your error message but I can write usage of useRef

```
const inputRef = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
  inputRef.current.setAttribute('directory', '');
 inputRef.current.setAttribute('webkitdirectory', '');
}, [inputRef ]);


  return <Input ref={inputRef} /> ;
```

Comment: What is folderInput?